# Does not contain constructor & Non-invocable member Class C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a simple class by referring to a YouTube video, but I get errors.

Here are the errors:
[image: Error]

And here is my code:

```
public class Student
{
    public int stdAge;
    public int stdiD;
    public string stdCitizenship;

    public void printStudent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Student Age: " + stdAge);
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID: " + stdiD);
        Console.WriteLine("Student Citizenship:" + stdCitizenship);

    }

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student std1 = new Student("Roslin Hashim");


        std1.stdAge(26);
        std1.stdiD(520308);
        std1.stdCitizenship("Malaysia");
        std1.printStudent();
    }
}
```

How do I know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: To set value of field/[property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295104/1997232)) you have to use following syntax: `std1.stdAge = 26;`.

Comment: That only vaguely looks like C#. If that's actually what's shown in the youtube video, close it now and go find a different source.

Comment: In C# we name public things **L**ikeThis, not **l**ikeThis

Comment: Add a constructor that takes a string: ```public Student(string urString) {/*Your code in here*/ }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting your values properly.  I assume you were trying to set `stdAge`, `stdiD` and `stdCitizenship` by doing the following:

```
    std1.stdAge(26);
    std1.stdiD(520308);
    std1.stdCitizenship("Malaysia");
```

You're using them like functions when they are not.  You need to put getters and setters on `stdAge`, `stdiD` and `stdCitizenship` and then set them using a simple `=` sign.  You also did not create a constructor that takes in 1 string argument.  So you'll need to do that.  The following code should do what you're trying to do.

```
public class Student
{
    //Setting getter and setters
    public int stdAge { get; set; }
    public int stdiD { get; set; }
    public string stdCitizenship { get; set; }

    //Here's the constructor you need
    public Student(string name) {
        //Code to do sometihng with name parameter here.
    }

    public void printStudent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Student Age: " + stdAge);
        Console.WriteLine("Student ID: " + stdiD);
        Console.WriteLine("Student Citizenship:" + stdCitizenship);    
    }    
}    

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student std1 = new Student("Roslin Hashim");    
        
        std1.stdAge = 26;
        std1.stdiD = 520308;
        std1.stdCitizenship = "Malaysia";
        std1.printStudent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, i seeee. Thanks a lottt!